# Override a method without base class seeing it

Tags: python

**This is a terrible idea, but I am refactoring some poorly designed code and this will make it easier.**

In Python I would like to override a method, but have calls from the base class methods still use their own version. Something like this:

```py
class Base:
  def foo(self):
    self.bar();

  def bar(self):
    return "base"

class Derived:
  def bar(self):
    return "derived"

d = Derived()
assert d.foo() == "base"
assert d.bar() == "derived"
```

Is something like that possible? `Base` is a built-in class so I cannot modify it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. `d.foo()` is effectively `Base.foo(d)`; `self` is the `Derived` instance whose `bar` attribute is the override.

Comment: "Base is a built-in class so I cannot modify it." Most builtins have the *opposite* "problem" in that they always call the original methods. What exactly are you working with?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't override ``foo`` as well to explicitly call the base class' method? E.g. are there too many or are they non-trivial?

Comment: Yeah there are too many and they are non-trivial. `Base` is actually `random.Random` and `bar()` is `getrandbits()`. Don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close but the problem you'll have is that your code, as written, will produce the following:

```
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d.foo()
    "derived"
>>> d.bar()
    "derived"
```

There are two ways you can fix this. First, you can modify `Base.foo` so that it references `Base` explicitly:

```
class Base:

    def foo(self):
        return Base.bar(self)

    def bar(self):
        return "base"
```

However, my understanding is that you cannot modify `Base`. Therefore, your next best option would be to create a wrapper for `Base` and inherit from that:

```
class BaseWrapper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = Base()

    def foo(self):
        self.inner.foo()

class Derived(BaseWrapper):

    def bar(self):
        return "derived"
```

This will produce the desired results with minimal maintenance effort on your part.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the wrapper is how the code is currently implemented, but it's not good because it means `Derived` is no longer an instance of `Base` for static type checking purposes. I guess I will have to fix the code properly!

Comment: Hmm, that is difficult. Let me see if I can't figure something out.